# atari breakout game ball bug?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently building an very simplified version of the Atari breakout game. After running this bit of code for around 5 seconds(after the ball makes around 3 loops around the board), the ball gets stuck in the right wall and does a weird jittery jumping motion. When I change the width/height properties of the ball or the board or any other element, it works fine. I'm just confused as to why this would be occurring. Here's the code:

```js
      var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
      var x = canvas.width/2;
      var y = canvas.height-30;
      var dx = 2;
      var dy = -2;
      var ballRadius = 10;
    
      function drawBall() {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0 , Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8)";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
      }
      function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        drawBall();
        drawPaddle();
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        if ((y + dy < ballRadius) || (y + dy > canvas.height - ballRadius)) {
          dy = -dy;
        }
    
        if ((x + dx < ballRadius) || (x + dy > canvas.width - ballRadius)) {
          dx = -dx;
        }
      }
    
      setInterval(draw, 10);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>Atari Breakout</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='breakout.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id='myCanvas' width='480' height='320'></canvas>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

The code isn't that clean, but I don't understand why the ball gets stuck in the right wall after ~ 6seconds?

Comment: `|| (x + dy > canv...`? Should it rather be `x + dx`?

Comment: one of your two conditions for inverting the direction must be a non strict comparison, otherwise, nothing will happen if `y + dy` and `canvas.height - ballRadius` are equal (same thing for the second inversion)